# I can ping www server, but cannot ping domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, ping

for example, I can ping www.example.com, but cannot ping example.com. It reports:

"Ping request could not find host example.com. please check the name and try again" (in DOS mode）

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should add real example here - hard to guess universal reason :-)
/If i must try then I'll said that mysite.com really not exist (in DNS terms - not have A record)/.

Comment: sorry, I'm afraid that the real name will be regarded as an advertisement.

Comment: Is this a problem? Is being able to ping your domain name a requirement for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't have an A record for example.com in DNS. Simply create one with the same settings as www.example.com

Comment: thanks, jelmers.  I have added A record to *.mysite.com, and I can open the pages in www.mysite.com. but when I open mysite.com in firefox, it reports server not found.

Comment: The A record should be to mysite.com, not *.mysite.com. If you added that, the failure to fetch the domain name might be cached on your computer (and any intermediate DNS server used in the query). Do a ipconfig /flushdns and restart firefox to clear the caches on your computer before trying again.

Comment: Can I say I have to add two A records for mysite.com and www.mysite.com seperately?

Comment: Yes, you need two A records if you want both mysite.com and www.mysite.com to point to your website.

Comment: Yes, you can say that. *.mysite.com and mysite.com are not the same so you need an A record for both. In other words, you need to create an A record for the naked domain (mysite.com).

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, is it immediately valid or it will take many hours to propagate (similar to change name server)?

Comment: A query that gave a negative result ("could not find host") should time out quite quickly, but not instantly. Might take a few minutes, so give it a bit of time.